# javascript write to textbox on iPhone not working but works on PC

Tags: javascript, iphone, textbox

I have a page that our field uses to quickly create notation for a job they did in the field. There is a series of drop down boxes and places to type in information and after they are done they click on a Generate Notes link which puts all the information together and dispays it in a TextBox. It works fine in Internet Explorer on a computer however when trying to access with an iPhone the text does not show in the TextBox. I could really use some help here. Here is part of the code that I have. This is the link to the temp as well to see how it should work.

http://forums.mycybernation.net/notegen/trial.html

Again works on PC but not on iPhone.

Thanks.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
 function CreateMsg() 
{
  var appCA = document.getElementById("MSG1");
  var appCA1 = document.getElementById("MSG2");
  var appEND = document.getElementById("MSG3");
  var origAPP = document.getElementById("MSG4");

  document.getElementById("Output").value = 

  appEND.innerHTML = "CA=" + 
document.forms[0].appCA.value + 
document.forms[0].appCA1.value + " | " +
document.forms[0].appEND.value + " " + 
document.forms[0].origAPP.value + " " + 
"\n\n";
}
</SCRIPT>


<A href="javascript:CreateMsg();">Generate Notes:</A> 

<BR><TEXTAREA class="TEXT_FIELD" id="OUTPUT" style="WIDTH: 320px" name="OUTPUT" rows="10" cols="75" TYPE="TEXT" INPUT ></TEXTAREA> <BR>
<SPAN id=MSG1>&nbsp;</SPAN> <BR>
<SPAN id=MSG2>&nbsp;</SPAN> <BR>
<SPAN id=MSG3>&nbsp;</SPAN> <BR>
<SPAN id=MSG4>&nbsp;</SPAN> <BR>

<BR></FORM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `textarea` id is `OUTPUT` whereas you're selecting an element with id `Output`. IE's version of the method is case-insensitive, but WebKit's is case-sensitive.

Comment: Lol, I knew it was something stupid. Thanks a million that helped greatly and is much appreciated!!!